# Tips to prevent repeating code in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have multiple chunks of code that repeat with slight variation, is there a more space efficient way of coding this? I tried using vectors, but to no avail. It just seems more error prone to markdown in this way

```
pACR_18_1 <- crude_test %>%
  select(uPCR.18.19.1, Sex, Diabetes, Hypertension) 
  
pACR_18_1 <- pACR_18_1 %>%
  mutate(uPCR_18_500 = ((uPCR.18.19.1*0.01768))) %>%
  mutate(uPCR_18_50 = ((uPCR.18.19.1*0.1768))) 

pACR_18_1 <- pACR_18_1 %>% 
  mutate(min_50 = (pmin(uPCR_18_50,1))) %>%
  mutate(min_500 = (pmin(uPCR_18_500,1))) %>%
  mutate(max_min_500 = (pmax(min_500,0.1))) %>%
  mutate(max_500 = (pmax(uPCR_18_500,1)))
           
pACR_18_1 <- pACR_18_1 %>%
  mutate(predACR_18_1 = exp(5.2659 + (0.2934 * log(min_50)) + (1.5643 * log(max_min_500)) + (1.1109 * log(max_500)) - 0.0773*Sex + 0.0797*Diabetes + 0.1265*Hypertension))
#This equation provides predicted ACR in mg/g, so need to convert to mg/mmol

pACR_18_1 <- pACR_18_1 %>%
  mutate(mmol_ACR_18_1 = predACR_18_1/8.84)
```

```
pACR_18_2 <- crude_test %>%
  select(uPCR.18.19.2, Sex, Diabetes, Hypertension) 
  
pACR_18_2 <- pACR_18_2 %>%
  mutate(uPCR_18_500 = ((uPCR.18.19.2*0.01768))) %>%
  mutate(uPCR_18_50 = ((uPCR.18.19.2*0.1768))) 

pACR_18_2 <- pACR_18_2 %>% 
  mutate(min_50 = (pmin(uPCR_18_50,1))) %>%
  mutate(min_500 = (pmin(uPCR_18_500,1))) %>%
  mutate(max_min_500 = (pmax(min_500,0.1))) %>%
  mutate(max_500 = (pmax(uPCR_18_500,1)))
           
  
pACR_18_2 <- pACR_18_2 %>%
  mutate(predACR_18_2 = exp(5.2659 + (0.2934 * log(min_50)) + (1.5643 * log(max_min_500)) + (1.1109 * log(max_500)) - 0.0773*Sex + 0.0797*Diabetes + 0.1265*Hypertension))
#This equation provides predicted ACR in mg/g, so need to conver to mg/mmol

pACR_18_2 <- pACR_18_2 %>%
  mutate(mmol_ACR_18_2 = predACR_18_2/8.84)
```

I used the vector `all_uPCR <- c(pACR_18, pACR_18_1....)` but this did not work.

Comment: The usual way to handle something like this is to write a function to do the calculations, then call that function several times.  It's not just space efficient, it's much less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function and have that variable column name / names as an argument. Just need to embrace arguments by surrounding those with double braces in dplyr calls, like described in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection

An example with `mtcars` dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
carsf <- function(df, arg_col){
  # note the {{ }}
  df %>% select({{arg_col}}) %>% head(n=3)
}

head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

carsf(mtcars, mpg)
#>                mpg
#> Mazda RX4     21.0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0
#> Datsun 710    22.8
carsf(mtcars, cyl)
#>               cyl
#> Mazda RX4       6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag   6
#> Datsun 710      4
carsf(mtcars, disp)
#>               disp
#> Mazda RX4      160
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  160
#> Datsun 710     108
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>